# String Altering Program Outputting Random Characters

Tags: c++, string, input, output

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string output;
string words;
int i;

int main()
{
    cin >> words; // gets words from user
    output = ""; // readys the output string
    i = 0;      // warms up the calculator
    int size = words.size();  // size matters
    while (i <= size) { // loops through each character in "words"       (can't increment in the function?)
        output += ":regional_indicator_" + words[i] +':';  //     appends output with each letter from words plus a suffix and prefix
        ++i;
    }               

    cout << output << endl; // prints the output
    return 0;
}
```

My intentions with this code is decently clear I'd like to think. Simply take a sentence, replace all characters with that character + a suffix and prefix.
My problem is that, when ran in the debugger, I'll input `"hello world"` and the program will output `"osss"`.

I have absolutely no education in C++ and am at a total loss here. Is it my `++i`?

Comment: `cin >> words;` will only read one word, not all the words in the line.

Comment: You can't use `+` to concatenate string literals and characters. One of the arguments has to be a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
output += ":regional_indicator_" + words[i] +':';  //     appends output with each letter from words plus a suffix and prefix
```

doesn't work. The overloading of the `+` operator for string concatenation only works if one of the arguments is a `std::string`. But you're trying to use it with a C-string literal and a `char`. Change that to:

```
output += "regional_indicator_";
output += words[i];
output += ':';
```

This uses the `+=` overloading of `std::string` for each part, and does what you want.

Also, if you want to read a whole line, not just a single word, use:

```
getline(cin, words);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked perfectly, and I threw a if loop around it to handle spaces. I'll start reading Kerninghan and Ritchie tonight so I don't have to ask any more stupid questions.